# Изменение настроек 1с bitrix

Tags: windows, битрикс, установка, настройка, настройки

Устанавливаю 1c-bitrix и получаю следующее окно (которое до того как все параметры станут зелеными и перестанут быть красными - не хочет загружаться дальше)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите изменить настройки

date.timezone

mbstring.func_overload

```
Server environment  Bitrix Virtual Appliance version 4.2 or higher  Unknown environment

Processing .htaccess    Enabled                                     Disabled
```

Answer (score 0):

Откройте в своём окружении файл php.ini и пропишите там параметры которые предлагает битрикс

Comment: date.timezone="Europe/Moscow"

mbstring.func_overload = 2
Я поменял. Но переменных 


    Server environment  
    Processing .htaccess    
я не нашел
Что мне с ними делать?

Comment: У вас в настройках апача не включена обработка файла .htaccess. Нужно ее включить - https://www.linode.com/docs/web-servers/apache/how-to-set-up-htaccess-on-apache/