# Ошибка при открытии phpmyadmin

Tags: php, битрикс, phpmyadmin, веб-сервер, битрикс24

я установил в php.ini следующие переменные (как было отвечено на странице [Изменение настроек 1с bitrix](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1011934/%d0%98%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba-1%d1%81-bitrix), правда я так и не нашел место где задаются переменные

```
Server environment  Bitrix Virtual Appliance version 4.2 or higher  Unknown environment

Processing .htaccess    Enabled                                     Disabled
```

Я только поменял значения

```
date.timezone="Europe/Moscow"

mbstring.func_overload = 2
```

Но при установке 1с битрикса нужно задать, созданную мною базу данных.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При открытии http://localhost/pma на экране появляется сообщение

```
Deprecated: The mbstring.func_overload directive is deprecated in Unknown on line 0

Fatal error: Uncaught UnexpectedValueException: Overloading of string functions using mbstring.func_overload is not supported by phpseclib. in C:\Apache24\htdocs\pma\vendor\phpseclib\phpseclib\phpseclib\bootstrap.php:11 Stack trace: #0 C:\Apache24\htdocs\pma\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php(66): require() #1 C:\Apache24\htdocs\pma\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php(56): composerRequirec1a85a0e014f9e891c8f3df09ff040e3('decc78cc4436b12...', 'C:\\Apache24\\htd...') #2 C:\Apache24\htdocs\pma\vendor\autoload.php(7): ComposerAutoloaderInitc1a85a0e014f9e891c8f3df09ff040e3::getLoader() #3 C:\Apache24\htdocs\pma\libraries\common.inc.php(91): require_once('C:\\Apache24\\htd...') #4 C:\Apache24\htdocs\pma\index.php(27): require_once('C:\\Apache24\\htd...') #5 {main} thrown in C:\Apache24\htdocs\pma\vendor\phpseclib\phpseclib\phpseclib\bootstrap.php on line 11
```

Comment: Тут не учебный центр имени NikolajSarry. Тут много людей. Если нужен персональный тренер, то вы туда пишите

Comment: Поиск в гугл. https://idea.1c-bitrix.ru/24451/. Проблемы битрикса и php старших версий. Отключите в php.ini:
````error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_WARNING & ~E_DEPRECATED
````

Comment: Битрикс в данный момент заточен под php версии 7.1 на более свежих версиях возможны ошибки. Поэтому рекомендуется использовать версию 7.1

Comment: @СергейМишин причем тут я можно задать вопрос? Кроме того, что я дал ответ в первом вопросе автора? Может вы ошиблись ником при упоминании?

Comment: @vladdv861-dvin здесь вам не форум. Оставьте один актуальный вопрос в котором изложите суть проблемы. В постановке вопроса укажите версии ПО которое используете, а также разворачиваете битрикс в собственном окружении или используете веб-окружение/виртуальную машину от битрикса. На форуме битрикса и в документации уже максимально разобрали весь процесс установки. Не вижу проблем поставить себе VirtualBox и там все развернуть из коробки и пользоваться если хотите локально. Хотите на сервере - ставьте centos и разворачивайте готовое окружение битрикса. Все уже там настроено за вас.

Comment: @NikolajSarry нет. я все верно написал. А почему? См. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1012285/revisions

Comment: @СергейМишин понял. Занятно.